# How to load Fragment only once and save its state?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I have one mainActivity from where i am calling the list of fragments.

Now,in this list i have one fragment called MyAccount which display the list of Account Details,using webservice.

What i want is i want to load the myAccount Details only once(first time) fragment is loaded,not every time.(which is happening right now).Moreover, i want to set one refresh button in action bar,so on click of that refresh button/image the account details will be load and display.

Here is my Implementation ::

**getFragement() in Main Acitivty ::**

```
private List<Fragment> getFragments()
    {
        List<Fragment> fList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();


            fList.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment1.class.getName()));


            fList.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment2.class.getName()));



            fList.add(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment3.class.getName()));



        fList.add(MyAccountFragment.newInstance(this,"My Account"));
        fList.add(ReportFragment.newInstance(this,"Reports"));
        fList.add(SettingsListFragment.newInstance(this,"Settings"));

        return fList;
    }
```

**Calling the adapter ::**

```
actionbartabmenuAdapter = new ActionBarTabMenuAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments,this);
awesomePager.setAdapter(actionbartabmenuAdapter);
```

**Adapter ::**

```
private class ActionBarTabMenuAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter  {
        Activity context;
        Context ctx;
        private List<Fragment> fragments;

        public ActionBarTabMenuAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments,Context ctx,)
        {
            super(fm);
            this.context=(Activity) ctx;

            this.fragments = fragments;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() 
        {
            return fragments.size();
        }
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            System.out.println("position of fragment--"+position);
            return this.fragments.get(position);
        }
    }
```

**onTabSelected/Reselected Method ::**

```
@Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tabposition, FragmentTransaction fragmentposition) {
        System.out.println("Tab Reselected method");

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tabposition, FragmentTransaction fragmentposition) {

        awesomePager.setCurrentItem(tabposition.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tabposition, FragmentTransaction fragmentposition) {
        System.out.println("Tab unselected method");

    }
```

**MyAccountFragment ::**

```
public class MyAccountFragment extends SherlockFragment{

    static MyAccountFragment f ;
    ListView list_subscriberInfo;
    ProgressDialog pd = null;
    MyAccountInfo myAccountInfo = new MyAccountInfo();
    private MyApplication appContext;
    static Context context;

    public static MyAccountFragment newInstance(Activity ctx,String string)
    {
        f = new MyAccountFragment();
        context=ctx;
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSherlockActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // now onCreateOptionsMenu(...) is called again
        this.setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_account, container, false);
        list_subscriberInfo = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.list_subscriberInfo);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) 
    {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_new, menu);
    }

    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) 
    {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        pd=new ProgressDialog(context);
        if (isVisibleToUser) 
        {
            pd =ProgressDialog.show(context,null, "Please Wait..", true);
            pd.setContentView(R.layout.progress);
            Thread thread = new Thread(getPersonalInfo);
            thread.start();
        }
        else
        {
            if(pd.isShowing())
            {
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please note in myAccountFragment i have set setUserVisibleHint() to dislpay the account info only when this fragment get visibility true.

I know that my Problem's solution is setOffScreenLimit() but i don't know where/how to set it my implementation.

But how to use both means visible the my account only when fragment get visible and also not load the fragment every time.? Load only only when the refresh button is clicked in action bar(second time).

Hope i am clear.

Thanks in advance...

**EDIT::**

Applying LuksProg's Logic...

**MyContainerActivity ::**

```
MyAccountFragment mSavedAccount;

public void cacheAccount(MyAccountFragment account) {
        mSavedAccount = account;
    }

    public Object getCachedAccount() {
        return mSavedAccount;
    }
```

**MyAccountFragment ::**

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        containerActivity = (ButtonPayActivity) getActivity();
        pd=new ProgressDialog(context);

        if (containerActivity.getCachedAccount() != null)
        {
            //Do nothing
            if(pd.isShowing())
            {
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // the data isn't available so this must be a fresh start
            // start the thread, remember to use act.cacheAccount() when the thread finishes
            pd =ProgressDialog.show(context,null, "Please Wait..", true);
            pd.setContentView(R.layout.progress);
            Thread thread = new Thread(getPersonalInfo);
            thread.start();
        }
    }
```

**EDIT 2 ::**

After applying the logic for progress dialog i faced the following issues.

what i have done is show and cancel the progress dialog but after i move to the very next tab of my Account my app gets crashed...

```
awesomePager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position)
            {
                //supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                 if (position == 4)
                 {
                        MyAccountFragment df = (MyAccountFragment) actionbartabmenuAdapter.getItem(position);
                    if (df.getThread() != null && df.getThread().isAlive()) 
                    {
                        df.showDialog();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        df.cancelDialog();
                    }
                }
             }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
            }
        });
```

**myAccountFragment ::**

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        containerActivity = (ButtonPayActivity) getActivity();
        pd=new ProgressDialog(context);

        if (containerActivity.getCachedAccount() != null)
        {

            if(pd.isShowing())
            {
                pd.dismiss();
            }
        }
        else
        {

            pd =ProgressDialog.show(context,null, "Please Wait..", true);
            pd.setContentView(R.layout.progress);
            thread = new Thread(getPersonalInfo);
            thread.start();
        }
    }

    public void showDialog() 
    {
        if (pd != null) 
        {
            pd.show(); // the dialog will be started from the OnPageChangeListener only
        }
    }

    public void cancelDialog() 
    {
        if (pd != null) 
        {
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    }

    public Thread getThread() 
    {
        return thread;
    }
```

**Logcat ::**

```
12-24 20:31:20.076: E/AndroidRuntime(15596): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-24 20:31:20.076: E/AndroidRuntime(15596): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.app.home.ReportFragment
12-24 20:31:20.076: E/AndroidRuntime(15596):    at com.example.app.ContainerActivity$1.onPageSelected(ContainerActivity.java:151)
12-24 20:31:20.076: E/AndroidRuntime(15596):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:438)
12-24 20:31:20.076: E/AndroidRuntime(15596):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:405)
12-24 20:31:20.076: E/AndroidRuntime(15596):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:386)
12-24 20:31:20.076: E/AndroidRuntime(15596):    at com.example.app.ContainerActivity.onTabSelected(ContainerActivity)
12-24 20:31:20.076: E/AndroidRuntime(15596):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.selectTab(ActionBarImpl.java:531)
12-24 20:31:20.076: E/AndroidRuntime(15596):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$TabImpl.select(ActionBarImpl.java:912)
12-24 20:31:20.076: E/AndroidRuntime(15596):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView$TabClickListener.onClick(ScrollingTabContainerView.java:504)
12-24 20:31:20.076: E/AndroidRuntime(15596):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
12-24 20:31:20.076: E/AndroidRuntime(15596):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
12-24 20:31:20.076: E/AndroidRuntime(15596):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-24 20:31:20.076: E/AndroidRuntime(15596):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-24 20:31:20.076: E/AndroidRuntime(15596):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-24 20:31:20.076: E/AndroidRuntime(15596):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-24 20:31:20.076: E/AndroidRuntime(15596):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-24 20:31:20.076: E/AndroidRuntime(15596):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-24 20:31:20.076: E/AndroidRuntime(15596):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-24 20:31:20.076: E/AndroidRuntime(15596):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-24 20:31:20.076: E/AndroidRuntime(15596):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Still Problem persists and just for curiosity i apply the following thing in my code with no success.
Now i get the progress dialog earlier means before the myAccount Fragment get visibity,so i applied `onActivityCreated()` to in `setUserVisibleHint()` and keep the rest of the thing as it is.

But then also my app gets crashed and i got following log..

**Logcat ::**

```
12-24 20:22:26.125: E/AndroidRuntime(14861): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-24 20:22:26.125: E/AndroidRuntime(14861): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-24 20:22:26.125: E/AndroidRuntime(14861):    at com.example.app.home.MyAccountFragment.setUserVisibleHint(MyAccountFragment.java:183)
12-24 20:22:26.125: E/AndroidRuntime(14861):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:102)
12-24 20:22:26.125: E/AndroidRuntime(14861):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:649)
12-24 20:22:26.125: E/AndroidRuntime(14861):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:783)
12-24 20:22:26.125: E/AndroidRuntime(14861):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:433)
12-24 20:22:26.125: E/AndroidRuntime(14861):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:405)
12-24 20:22:26.125: E/AndroidRuntime(14861):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:386)
12-24 20:22:26.125: E/AndroidRuntime(14861):    at com.example.app.ContainerActivity.onTabSelected(ContainerActivity.java:385)
12-24 20:22:26.125: E/AndroidRuntime(14861):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.selectTab(ActionBarImpl.java:531)
12-24 20:22:26.125: E/AndroidRuntime(14861):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$TabImpl.select(ActionBarImpl.java:912)
12-24 20:22:26.125: E/AndroidRuntime(14861):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView$TabClickListener.onClick(ScrollingTabContainerView.java:504)
12-24 20:22:26.125: E/AndroidRuntime(14861):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
12-24 20:22:26.125: E/AndroidRuntime(14861):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
12-24 20:22:26.125: E/AndroidRuntime(14861):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-24 20:22:26.125: E/AndroidRuntime(14861):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-24 20:22:26.125: E/AndroidRuntime(14861):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-24 20:22:26.125: E/AndroidRuntime(14861):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-24 20:22:26.125: E/AndroidRuntime(14861):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-24 20:22:26.125: E/AndroidRuntime(14861):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-24 20:22:26.125: E/AndroidRuntime(14861):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-24 20:22:26.125: E/AndroidRuntime(14861):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-24 20:22:26.125: E/AndroidRuntime(14861):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: is your app contains ABS+ tabs+ multifragments? right?

Comment: @Sharmilee yes,you are absolutely right...

Answer (score 2):

> i want to load the myAccount Details only once(first time) fragment
>   is loaded,not every time.(which is happening right now).

If you want to load the data only once, then you'll need to cache it at the activity/fragment level once you retrieve it the first time. So, you will need to implement two methods in your `Activity` containing the fragment to set and get the data:

```
public void cacheAccount(Object account) {
    mSavedAccount = account;
}

public Object getCachedAccount() {
    return mSavedAccount;
}
```

Then in the `MyAccountFragment` fragment you'll implement the following logic:

- use one of the lifecycle methods to put the code for retrieving the data(so, don't use `setUserVisibleHint()`), like `onActivityCreated()`
- there, you will need to use the above methods to first see if the data isn't already available(if the fragment was previously loaded and the data was saved). If data is available then use it directly and don't start the retrieval tread, otherwise start the thread
- if the thread is started, when it finishes you'll need to set the data but also save it in the activity so it will be available on future uses of the `MyAccountFragment` fragment

Mock implementation:

```
// in the onActivityCreated() method:
// cast the activity
YourActivity act = (YourActivity) getActivity();
// check if the data isn't by any chance already available
if (act.getCachedAccount() != null) {
     // the data is already available so use it
} else {
     // the data isn't available so this must be a fresh start
     // start the thread, remember to use act.cacheAccount() when the thread finishes
}
```

Also, if you want to save the data across a configuration change you might want to use a fragment with the methods above which is set to retain the configuration(`setRetainInstance(true)` is called for it).

> Moreover, i want to set one refresh button in action bar,so on click
>   of that refresh button/image the account details will be load and
>   display.

This shouldn't be a problem, as a long as you remember to call `activity.cacheAccount()` when the retrieval thread finishes so you have the data available for future uses.

> I know that my Problem's solution is setOffScreenLimit() but i don't
>   know where/how to set it my implementation.

`setOffScreenLimit()` will increase the number of fragments that the adapter keeps in memory. Depending on how heavy are your fragments it might work but in generally you should avoid using bigger values(in your case you'll be basically holding in memory all of `ViewPager`'s fragments).

On a side note keep in mind that your current implementation of the `ViewPager`'s adapter(passing it a list of pre built fragments) will fail in certain cases as the list of fragments that you build will not hold the fragments that the `ViewPager` actually uses.

Edit
Implementation:

```
private SparseArray<Fragment> getFragments() {
     // I used a SparseArray but a list will also do
     SparseArray<Fragment> fList = new SparseArray<Fragment>();
     fList.put(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment1.class.getName()));
     fList.put(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment2.class.getName()));
     fList.put(Fragment.instantiate(this,Fragment3.class.getName()));
     fList.put(MyAccountFragment.newInstance(this,"My Account"));
     fList.put(ReportFragment.newInstance(this,"Reports"));
     fList.put(SettingsListFragment.newInstance(this,"Settings"));
     return fList;
}

// the adapter
private class ActionBarTabMenuAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter  {
        Activity context;
        Context ctx;
        private SparseArray<Fragment> fragments;

        public ActionBarTabMenuAdapter(FragmentManager fm, SparseArray<Fragment> fragments,Context ctx) {
            super(fm);
            this.context=(Activity) ctx;
            this.fragments = fragments;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragments.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            System.out.println("position of fragment--"+position);
            return this.fragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        fragments.put(position, null);
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    } 

        @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Fragment f = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        fragments.put(position, f);
        return f;
    }
    }
```

Second edit:
To show the Dialog only when you are at the `MyAccountFragment` fragment:

```
 mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    if (position == 3) {
                MyAccountFragment df = (MyAccountFragment) adapter.getItem(position);
            if (df.getThread() != null && df.getThread().isAlive()) {
                df.showDialog();
            } else {
                df.cancelDialog();
            }
        }
     }

// rest of the methods
 }
```

And those methods are implemented in the `MyAccountFragment`:

```
  public void showDialog() {
        if (pd != null) {
            pd.show(); // the dialog will be started from the OnPageChangeListener only
        }
    }

    public void cancelDialog() {
        if (pd != null) {
            pd.dismiss(); // remeber to call this when the thread finishes
        }
    }

    public Thread getThread() {
        return mThread; // this will be the reference to the started thread
    }
```

Comment: As you said my current implementation  of viewpager may get failed in certain cases.so can you please correct me in that part also?

Comment: @AndroidLearner I've edited my answer with an example. You need to keep the references synchronized.

Comment: `fragments.delete(position);` and `fragments.put(position, f);` shows me an error `The method put(int, Fragment) is undefined for the type List<Fragment>`

Comment: @AndroidLearner I've used a `SparseArray` which has a `put()` method, which a `List` doesn't have. If you want to use a `List` then use its `set(position, fragment)` method.

Comment: i have set your logic in my code.please check edit.problem m facing now is that whenever i click on the previous or next fragment of the myaccount,it shows me the progress dialog.how to resolve that?

Comment: @AndroidLearner *whenever i click on the previous or next fragment of the myaccount,* - I'm not sure I understand the problem. I'm guessing you see the `ProgressDialog` starting whenever you get to the fragments adjacent to `MyAccountFragment` which is normal. I don't know what's your app logic but I would advise you to use an embedded `ProgressBar` which would appear only when the `MyAccountFragment` is actually showing. Otherwise, to keep the `ProgressDialog` you'll need to implement it in an `OnPageChangeListener` outside of the fragment.

Comment: whenever i click on the previous or next fragment of the myaccount, means i have list which contains 6 fragments,so if i click directly Reports Tab(which comes next to the myAccountFragment),then it shows the view of current fragment + progressdialog of myAccount(which i have started in OnActivityCreated() of myAccountFragment),so this is my problem...and i faced the same issue earlier also so to resolve this, i have set `setUserVisibleHint()` in myAccountFragment. Hope i am clear ?

Comment: @AndroidLearner it's normal the dialog appears because the fragment will be initialized before it's visible to the user for efficiency. I've edited my answer on how you might handle the dialog.

Comment: i applied your logic for progress dialog but my app gets crash when i press the very next tab of the MyAccountFragment.I have explained this thing in my EDIT2.So please check my edit2.Moreover,to maintain the state of the myAccountFragment means if my app goes in background then also it should not lost its state which happens now.If my app goes in background and i load the fragment again,i got the progress dialog again even if i have not pressed the refresh button.I hope m not bothering you too much...please help me to get rid of this issue...

Comment: @AndroidLearner The cast exception is appearing because in the `onPageSelected()` you check for position `4` but the account fragment is on position `3`. I don't understand the second stacktrace you don't need `setUserVisibleHint()` implement the logic only on `onActivityCreated()`. The account info is kept by the activity but you need to save it. To keep the data even if the activity goes in the background then save it in the `onSaveInstanceState()` and restore it when the app comes from background. If you need to save the data even more then use a database, a file etc.